# Why data can not replaced with types.BlendData

Tags: python

I'm reading the Blender API, when I came to this line:

```
data = types.BlendData
```

I realized bpy.data is a short hand of bpy.types.BlendData, so I tried to change my code from

```
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('mm')
```

to this one

```
mesh = bpy.types.BlendData.meshes.new('mm')
```

and I got this error

```
AttributeError: type object 'BlendData' has no attribute 'meshes'
```

Can you tell me where I was going wrong?

Comment: Hello, `meshes` is not a static member of the `bpy.types.BlendData` class. You need to access it through an instance of the class (`bpy.data`). I don't think this question is suitable for this site. It really is more a question about python rather than Blender which can easily be answered on stackoverflow or by following a crash course on python. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but I could not find where the bpy.data is instantialized , it is a bit related to Python though

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the features of the python API, most of what you get in Python is just handles for objects that are in fact initialized behind the scenes by the c++ source code. You might want to dive into the source code rather than the API if you want to have access to these calls